# unable to add record in a kendoGrid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-combobox

I have a problem, working over for three days, but can't find any solution!!!
 In the document.ready, i create a datasource with subobjects

```
var datasource = [
  {
   "category": {
      "id_category": 1,
      "desc_category": "Beverages"
  },
   "id_product": 1,
      "desc_product": "Chai",
      "price": "11",
      "id_category": 1
  },
  {
   "category": {
      "id_category": 2,
      "desc_category": "Condiments"
  },
    "id_product": 2,
      "desc_product": "Aniseed Syrup",
      "price": "12",
      "id_category": 2
 }
]
```

and then i create a kendogrid

```
var kendoGrid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({

    selectable: true,
    dataSource: datasource,
    resizable: true,
    toolbar: [{
        name: "create",
        text: "Add Something"
    }],
    columns: [
        { field: "desc_product", title: "Description", width: 100 },
        { field: "price", title: "Price", width: 100 },
        { field: "id_product", title: "Category", width: 200, editor: categoryDropDownEditor, template: '#=category.desc_category#' },
        {
            command: [{
                name: "destroy",
                text: "Delete",
                confirmation: "Are you sure?"
            },
            {
                name: "edit",
                text: {
                edit: "Edit",
                update: "Update",
                cancel: "Cancel"
            }
            }
            ]
        }
    ],
    width: 200,
    height: 300,
    editable: editable = {
        mode: "inline",
        confirmation: "Are you sure?"
    }
});
```

and finally the function to fill the combobox in the grid in edit mode

```
function categoryDropDownEditor(container, options) {
var ds = [
{         
      "id_category": 1,
      "desc_category": "Beverages"
},
{
   "id_category": 2,
   "desc_category": "Condiments"
},
{
   "id_category": 3,
   "desc_category": "Confections"
},
{
   "id_category": 4,
   "desc_category": "Produce"
},
{
   "id_category": 5,
   "desc_category": "Sea Food"
}
];

$('<input data-text-field="desc_category" data-value-field="id_category" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>"')
  .appendTo(container)
  .kendoComboBox({
      index: 0,
      placeholder: "Select Category",
      dataTextField: "desc_category",
      dataValueField: "id_category",
      dataSource: ds
  })
}
```

the problem is that when I try to add a new record, it runs an error (runtime error: category is undefined).

can someone tell me if the datasources are right?
is the structure of the code right?
Where is the problem?

hope someone can help me!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a new record, you should set a default value in the columns.field.
The error throws on because the classe_iva variable is not declared. Try to declare it as global.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I have same problem but actually I don't get it what is the classe_iva and how to declare it? Is there any sample to help?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you create a new record `category` is not defined and is not defined because you don't have a `schema.model` in your `DataSource`. Before invoking the `categoryDropDownEditor` function, it actually instantiates the `template` and it produces the error.

Fixing the error in the `template` is pretty easy, you just need to do something like:

```
template: '#= data.category ? data.category.desc_category : 1 #'
```

Which checks that the `data` of current row actuall has `category` defined.

*BUT* this will bring you into the next problem that is that you cannot close the `popup` because there is no `schema.model` definition.

You might try defining the `DataSource` as:

```
var datasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data  : [
        {
            "category"    : {
                "id_category"  : 1,
                "desc_category": "Beverages"
            },
            "id_product"  : 1,
            "desc_product": "Chai",
            "price"       : "11",
            "id_category" : 1
        },
        {
            "category"    : {
                "id_category"  : 2,
                "desc_category": "Condiments"
            },
            "id_product"  : 2,
            "desc_product": "Aniseed Syrup",
            "price"       : "12",
            "id_category" : 2
        }
    ],
    schema: {
        model: {
            id    : "id_category",
            fields: {
                desc_product: { type: "string" },
                price       : { type: "number" }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: But did you try my answer? What is your problem?

Comment: I posted the complete code above, using your suggestions, but the problem is the same, datasource is undefined when adding a new record.